# After grouping and sorting: Why is my python dataframe column name row, not in a single row?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, grouping

Firstly, I am not sure that I am doing this the best way, so alternatives appreciated!

I have a python pandas dataframe which I have created:
`raw_data = {'Name' : pd.Series(['david','andrew','calvin','david','calvin','david'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f']),'Age' : pd.Series([35, 40, 5, 35, 5, 35], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name','Age'])`

I want to now groupby and also sort (based on the frequency of the count of the occurrences of 'Name') and return the top 2 records. ie the following output:

```
  Name Count
david      3
calvin     2
```

I start by adding a "Count" column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name','Age'])
```

Gives:

```
     Name   Age Count
a   david   35  3
b   andrew  39  1
c   calvin  5   2
d   david   34  3
e   calvin  5   2
f   david   35  3
```

I then can group and sort this with the below code:

```
df[['Name','Count']].groupby('Name').count().sort_values('Count',ascending=0).head(2)
```

This is where I have the problem, the data is "correct", but the column headers appear to be in separate rows...See the screenshot:
[Column Header Alignment problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C47GM.png)

I have 3 questions

1) Why does this happen?

2) How can I fix it?

3) Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

[EDIT] - I have answered question 2, (How to fix it). Apparently i need to reset the index:

```
df.reset_index()
```

Would love to know, why and is there a better way?

Comment: what's wrong with calling `reset_index()` on your code?

Comment: nothing... I just didn't realise i needed to... Just wondering why the index was changed in the first place?

Comment: your index gets set to what you groupby and the aggregation columns, this is expected operation

Comment: OK. Thanks. That helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print df

#     Name  Age
#a   david   35
#b  andrew   40
#c  calvin    5
#d   david   35
#e  calvin    5
#f   david   35

df1 =  df.groupby('Name').apply(len)
print df1

#Name
#andrew    1
#calvin    2
#david     3
#dtype: int64
print df1.nlargest(2).reset_index(name='Count')

#     Name  Count
#0   david      3
#1  calvin      2
```